# history list in bash always truncated to 5000 lines at new login

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt, readline

Similar to the [5000 line limitation problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20861/13496) when first thing in **.bashrc** I have 
`export HISTSIZE=10001`
 and
 `export HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE`

My users do not have `~/.inputrc` files and the system-wide `/etc/inputrc` file, unchanged default for Ubuntu 11.10, does not have any `history-size` defined. Nor does the `readline` man page show any default for it, except implying **(0)** or unlimited.

Yet every time I login my prompt shows that I have only 5000, despite having added many more unique command lines during my last session, or saving with `history -w` without having logged off.

Where is this limitation set and how can I override it?

My prompt and other possibly interesting settings from **~/.bashrc** or files it sources:

```
PS1='\u@\h\w \d,\t\$ (\!) '
HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace
HISTSIZE=10001
export HISTIGNORE="[   ]*:&:bg:fg:exit"
export HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"  
shopt -s histappend
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S " 
shopt -s histreedit
```

Example prompt:

```
master@quant~/dev Mon Feb 27,10:08:29$ (5721)
```

To answer some comments:

```
# to unpollute from other concurrent sessions, which previously already truncated file to 5000 at login:
master@ventana~ Mon Feb 27,18:47:35$ (9220) history -w  

master@ventana~ Mon Feb 27,18:51:34$ (9220) history |wc
   9219   69109  795143
master@ventana~ Mon Feb 27,18:51:51$ (9220) wc -l ~/.bash_history
18442 /home/master/.bash_history

# ignoring timestamps, nominally every other line like #1328201645
master@ventana~ Mon Feb 27,18:51:58$ (9220) grep -vc "^#[0-9]\{10\}$" .bash_history
9222
```

Comment: Show us how you setup your prompt in your bash init file.

Comment: Also please show `wc -l ~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 2):

I may have a working theory on this.

Previously I had

```
HISTSIZE=10001
```

However actual lines in ~/.bash_history appear like

```
#1341908063
w;df
#1341908291
wizmo reboot!
#1341909327
sc stop uxsms; sleep 1; sc start UxSms
```

In other words, every other line is a timestamp due to my `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S "` shell environment setting.

So for a history of 5000 commands, 10000 lines in the file would be needed.

Now I set the limit to
    HISTSIZE=20001

and finally see my prompt keeping more that 5000 history commands *after* a fresh new login.