# bash history truncated to 2000 at new login after upgrade to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc

Ubuntu 14.04 with this setup worked fine .

Recently re installed my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 and every time I create a new terminal , the history get truncated to 2000 lines.
I use both Tilda and XFCE terminal , creating/destroyng a lot of terminals during the day

```
 bash --version
 GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Here the relevants environment variables :

```
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
HISTFILE=/home/andrea/.bash_history
HISTFILESIZE=50000
HISTSIZE=50000
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

and here the section of my bashrc (which get sourced by ~/.bashrc)

```
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
export HISTFILESIZE=50000
export HISTSIZE=50000
#change to default , ignoreboth , no dups and no commands beginning with space
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
set -o vi
shopt -s histappend
```

already checked those questions :

- [history list in bash always truncated to 5000 lines at new login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32758/history-list-in-bash-always-truncated-to-5000-lines-at-new-login)
- [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

  tried moving the bashrc part to bash_profile , without any change.
  Any idea?

update :
changing $HISTFILE seems to do the trick , now the row count is increasing