# .inputrc vs .bashrc settings

Tags: bashrc, inputrc

I've noticed few settings in `.bashrc` and `.inputrc` files look the same or are similar, such as:

`shopt -s nocaseglob` vs `set completion-ignore-case`
`export HISTSIZE` vs `set history-size`
`export HISTFILESIZE` vs `set history-size`

Do `.inputrc` settings also affect the completion and the history size in python shell (if run inside the terminal)?

Is `HISTSIZE` limited by `history-size` or does it override it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `bash` manual:

> `history-size` (unset)
>
> Set the maximum number of history entries saved in the history
>                 list.  If set to zero, any existing history entries are deleted
>                 and no new entries are saved.  If set to a value less than zero,
>                 the number of history entries is not limited.  By default, the
>                 number of history entries is set to the value of the `HISTSIZE`
>                 shell variable.  If an attempt is made to set `history-size` to a
>                 non-numeric value, the maximum number of history entries will be
>                 set to 500.

So if you set `HISTSIZE`, don't set `history-size` in `.inputrc`. The readline library (for which `.inputrc` is the configuration) does not care what you set `HISTFILESIZE` to.  `HISTFILESIZE` is the size that the history file (`$HISTFILE`) is truncated to when a `bash` shell session exits (by `bash`, not by the readline library).

According to the question "[Is there a way to set the size of the history list in bash to more than 5000 lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-size-of-the-history-list-in-bash-to-more-than-5000-lin)", the `history-size` setting of the readline library seems to override the `HISTSIZE` setting in the shell, if both are set.

The `nocaseglob` shell option is not the same as the `completion-ignore-case` setting in `.inputrc`. The shell option is about filename globbing behaviour, while the readline setting has to do with filename completion (when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the command line).

The `.inputrc` settings affect all programs that uses the readline library, not just `bash`.

`bash` may be started *without* readline support by invoking it with the `--noediting` flag.

---

Note that both `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` are *shell variables*, not environment variables, and therefore do not need to be exported.